# How do i check for a valid database connection using JDBCTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am using JDBCTemplate in my spring boot application and successfully connected to my AWS rds instance, but i noticed using AutoWired im not entirely sure how the connection is made and how to check for a valid connection, i want to throw an exception if the connection to the database is invalid. this is the way it connects, it takes the database information from application.properties.

```
 private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
 public AwsBarcodeDao(@Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbc){
 jdbcTemplate=jdbc;
```

}

there seems to be no indication of unsucessful connection until i try to do something like this, which is the actual query:

```
final String selectProductSql = "SELECT barcodeOrUpc, productName FROM DB WHERE barCodeOrUpc="+barcode+";";

    products =   jdbcTemplate.query(selectProductSql, new ProductRowMapper());
```

Comment: If you don't see any error during the boot I would assume there is no issue with the connections. I am suspicious about your sql statement actually. Do you have a table with name "DB" ? I think this could be the problem. And it would be easier if you provide us the error message you encounter when you try to call the query.

Comment: no its not actually DB i just didnt want to publicly post it on stackoverflow

Comment: Can you share the error log. I still think it could be because of smth else than connection.

Comment: It should throw an error automatically if you there is no connection to the db and the app tries to perform an action on it.

Answer (score 2):

In your application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.validationQuery=your validation query
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=30000
```

other props can be:

```
testOnBorrow
testOnReturn
validationQueryTimeout
```

**commons-dbcp** has a configuration property validationQuery, this combined with testOnBorrow and testOnReturn could cause the statements you see.

**c3p0** has preferredTestQuery, testConnectionOnCheckin, testConnectionOnCheckout and idleConnectionTestPeriod